# How to get ui-sref working inside trustAsHtml?

Tags: angularjs

I have a activity state, and when there are no activities I would like to display a message. So I created a if/else statement that checks if the $scope activities has any content, if not it injects a certain code into the template.

```
  if(!$scope.activities.length){
    var empty = function(){
      $scope.renderHtml = function (htmlCode) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
      };
      $scope.body = '<div>There are no activities yet, <a ui-sref="home.users">click here to start following some friends!</a></div>';

    }
    empty()
  }
```

The problem is that `ui-sref` doesn't work, a normal 'a href` does work though. Are there any solid work arounds for this problem?

Comment: this isn't the right way to inject templates into your HTML.  You should only be storing HTML in variables when it is outside your control (User Defined Content).  use a router or `ng-include` to dynamically change templates instead.

Comment: @Claies it felt a bit hacky and weird. So I researched some more, and found this > http://jsfiddle.net/AlexFigueiredoo/yG6nY/1/ seems to be doing the job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this work I created a element with ng-show,

```
%div{"ng-show" => "activitiesHide"}
```

And this js,

```
activitiesService.loadActivities().then(function(response) {
  $scope.activities = response.data;

  if(!$scope.activities.length){
    $scope.activitiesHide = response.data
  }
})
```

I place the results from the service in the activities scope, and then check in the js if it has content. If not activate the activitesHide show.